# How to start method after returning ResponseEntity in controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to start method after returning ResponseEntity in controller? I have to run sql stored procedure but the time is up to 1h. When I am trying to do it in a new thread the main thread still wait for a response from database.

Comment: use `@Async` method: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.